# How can I call different functions based on the value when a <select> value changes?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to call different function on changing the select option

Here is the markup:

```
<p>With every selection change I want a different function to be called</p>

<select data-bind="options: availableMeals, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedMeal, optionsValue: 'value', event: {change: onChange}">
</select>
```

Here is my viewmodel:

```
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.availableMeals = ko.observableArray(
        [
         {name: "Standard (sandwich)", value: 0}, 
         {name: "Premium (lobster)", value: 34.95}, 
         {name: "Ultimate (whole zebra)",value: 290}
        ]
    );

    self.selectedMeal = ko.observable(self.availableMeals()[0]);

    // i want this when i change to sandwitch    
    self.onChange = function() {
        alert("for sandwitch");
    };

    // i want this when i change to lobster 
    self.onChange1 = function() {
        alert("for lobster");
    };

    //i want this when i change to ultimate
    self.onChange2 = function() {
        alert("for whole zebra");
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

I know that I have only bind the `onChange` function with change event. What could be the way to call three different functions on different selections?

Here is the demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLv42zkL/

Comment: Why do you _need_ to call different functions? Why not call one function and use a switch on `selectedMeal` and implement the necessary functionality within the cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one function  `onChange` and then call other functions depending on the value of `selectedMeal`.

For example:

```js
function ReservationsViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.availableMeals = ko.observableArray(
    [{
      name: "Standard (sandwich)",
      value: 0
    }, {
      name: "Premium (lobster)",
      value: 34.95
    }, {
      name: "Ultimate (whole zebra)",
      value: 290
    }]
  );

  self.selectedMeal = ko.observable(self.availableMeals()[0]);

  self.onChange = function() {
    switch (self.selectedMeal()) {
      case 0:
        self.sandwichSelected();
        break;
      case 34.95:
        self.lobsterSelected();
        break;
      case 290:
        self.zebraSelected();
        break;
    }
  };

  self.sandwichSelected = function() {
    alert("for sandwich");
  };

  self.lobsterSelected = function() {
    alert("for lobster");
  };

  self.zebraSelected = function() {
    alert("for whole zebra");
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p>With every selection change I want a different function to be called</p>

<select data-bind="options: availableMeals, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedMeal, optionsValue: 'value', event: {change: onChange}">
</select>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9dy5tetu/)